# Question about API fetch order using .then and useEffect

Tags: reactjs, fetch-api, use-effect

I have a question about API fetching order using .then and useEffect. I'll do my best to explain to you all to get some helpful advice.

Expected outcome of the code:

1. On first load(when accessing the site for the first time), I want the pokemon with the index of 1 to appear as default (thus, the reason why I set the default value of the state variable "pokemonIndex" to 1. But nothing shows up..
2. Every time I click the button which will toggle the toggle() function, it will render the getRandomIndex() function, update the state variable "pokemonIndex" which will run the useEffect.
3. The useEffect will fetch a new API with the updated ${pokemonIndex}
4. The rest of the code seems pretty self-explanatory.

These are my questions:

1. In step 1 from above, why does nothing show up even though I set the default state variable to 1?
2. Every time I click the button which runs the toggle(), it fetches a new API. However, the network tab looks like this:
   [chrome network tab image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bp9gS.png)

- (please refer to the image) The blue lines represent the data fetched by every click of the button (the first one is the API fetched on the first load - question 1). However, it seems kinda wrong. For example, on the first click, it fetches pokemon with the Id 342 but also fetches the pokemon image with the Id of 1. There's a "mismatch". What I expected was on a button click, it will fetch (for example) a pokemon with the Id of 55 and also a image of the pokemon with the Id of 55 (like the blue lines I've drawn)

-> Is this normal behavior? Or is something messed up with my code. Thanks for reading such a long explanation. Thanks in advance!

```
export default function Testing() {
    
    const [randomPokemon, setRandomPokemon] = React.useState({})
    const [specifics, setSpecifics] = React.useState({})
    const [pokemonIndex, setPokemonIndex] = React.useState(1)
    const [prevPokemonIndex, setPrevPokemonIndex] = React.useState(0)
    const [disableButton, setDisableButton] = React.useState(false)
    
    function disableBtn() {
        setDisableButton(prevState => !prevState);
        setTimeout((setDisableButton), 1500)
    }
    
    function getRandomIndex(lowerBound, upperBound) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (upperBound - lowerBound + 1)) + lowerBound;
    };
    
        
    function toggle(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        const randomIndex = getRandomIndex(1, 898);
        setPokemonIndex(randomIndex);
        disableBtn()
    }
    
    React.useEffect(() => {
        fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${pokemonIndex}/`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            setRandomPokemon(data);
            setSpecifics({
                pokemonName: randomPokemon.name,
                pokemonId: randomPokemon.id,
                pokemonType: randomPokemon.types ? randomPokemon.types.map(type => type.type.name) : [],
                pokemonAbility: randomPokemon.abilities ? randomPokemon.abilities.map(ability => ability.ability.name) : [],
                pokemonImage: randomPokemon.sprites ? randomPokemon.sprites.other[`official-artwork`].front_default : []
            });
        })
    }, [pokemonIndex])
return (
        <div>
            <form>
                <button onClick={toggle} disabled={disableButton} type="button">Click me</button>
                <img src={specifics.pokemonImage}></img>
                <span>{specifics.pokemonName}</span>
                <span>{specifics.pokemonId}</span>
                <span>{specifics.pokemonType}</span>
                <span>{specifics.pokemonAbility}</span>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
```

Comment: Please add the rest of your component (that renders some JSX).

Comment: it's just some simple jsx to see if it's working properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is you're relying on `randomPokemon`, the state atom, in the `then` handler.

However, `setState` in React is asynchronous, so `randomPokemon` will not have changed by the time that `setSpecifics` is executed just after `setRandomPokemon`, so the specifics are always computed from data at the time of the effect's invocation (which, in effect (heh) is one "step" behind the just-loaded data).

You should instead use `data` (which is the fresh data you've just loaded) in that function – or, since `specifics` is strictly computed based on what `randomPokemon` is, it doesn't need to be a state atom at all, but can just be derived using `useMemo`, like so:

```
function getRandomIndex(lowerBound, upperBound) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (upperBound - lowerBound + 1)) + lowerBound;
}

export default function Testing() {
  const [pokemon, setPokemon] = React.useState(null); // Nothing loaded yet
  const [pokemonIndex, setPokemonIndex] = React.useState(1); // Which pokemon to load
  const [disableButton, setDisableButton] = React.useState(false);

  function disableBtn() {
    setDisableButton(true);
    setTimeout(() => setDisableButton(false), 1500);
  }

  function loadRandomPokemon(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const randomIndex = getRandomIndex(1, 898);
    setPokemonIndex(randomIndex);
    disableBtn();
  }

  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${pokemonIndex}/`)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then(setPokemon);
  });

  const specifics = React.useMemo(() => {
    if (!pokemon) {
      return null; // Not loaded, no specifics yet
    }
    return {
      pokemonName: pokemon.name,
      pokemonId: pokemon.id,
      pokemonType: pokemon.types ? pokemon.types.map((type) => type.type.name) : [],
      pokemonAbility: pokemon.abilities ? pokemon.abilities.map((ability) => ability.ability.name) : [],
      pokemonImage: pokemon.sprites ? pokemon.sprites.other[`official-artwork`].front_default : [],
    };
  }, [pokemon]);

  // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your advice! One question, it there a difference putting the getRandomIndex() out of the `export default function` and putting it inside like I did?

Comment: Well, it doesn't need to be recreated on every component invocation, so better not do that. It also makes it clearer to the reader that it's not strictly related to the component itself. You could similarly extract the specifics-computing function out; that would make it easier to test as a separate unit, too.

Comment: AH okay! Thanks! I modified your code a little bit:

```React.useEffect(() => {
        fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${pokemonIndex}/`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(setPokemon)
    }, [pokemonIndex]);
```

and 

`const [pokemon, setPokemon] = React.useState({});`

putting null as default value spit out an error saying image was not defined

Overall, thanks so much for the help man! Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${pokemonIndex}/`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
        setSpecifics({
            pokemonName: data.name,
            pokemonId: data.id,
            pokemonType: data.types ? data.types.map(type => type.type.name) : [],
            pokemonAbility: data.abilities ? data.abilities.map(ability => ability.ability.name) : [],
            pokemonImage: data.sprites ? data.sprites.other[`official-artwork`].front_default : []
        });

    })
}, [pokemonIndex])
```

Try this. That will work for you.